# How to use full calendar with c# asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, fullcalendar

I want to use the full calendar i/o  by creating a web service but i have not found any tutorials online. I have tried to search for tutorials but no success.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you've tried so far?

Comment: i have not started yet i  have no idea how to implement it. @MikkelMellumHviid

Comment: Found this on youtube: _https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKU5omv8X3s
Hope it helps.
I would recommend reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, before submitting a question again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a very basic [MVC example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1ganYd) on .NET Fiddle.

As mentioned by Mikkel in the comments you should take the time to read through how to ask a question.